# MySQL 5.1 command line problem: delete last char doesn't work

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, ubuntu-9.04

I can't delete the last character in a given line in the MySQL CLI, if I press "END", it will jump *on* the character and if I press "DEL", it will delete the char before that (like backspace).

Does anybody know a fix for that issue?

I use MySQL 5.1.31-1ubuntu2-log with normal shell access.

Thank you for assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears different on Linux/Windows.

Our solution was to add this line to ~/.editrc

bind -e

to see how editrc works:

https://www.mirbsd.org/htman/i386/man5/editrc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Erm ... Use cursor keys?

Comment: Well, you check the easy things first. Glad you got that one fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I heard recently that Shift-Del or Shift-Backspace works on some systems (mainly Mac), perhaps it can be used as a workaround for Ubuntu too?

**Update:** Does the End + Del/BS work normally when you're not inside MySQL prompt?